# How do I initialize this derived class that uses multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Say I have a class called `Vehicle`, and I have two sub classes called `Boat` and `Car`, which inherit from `Vehicle`.

Now say I have an amphibious vehicle, which uses multiple inheritance `AmphibiousVehicle(Boat, Car)`.

Now my question is: how should the `__init__` function of `AmphibiousVehicle` be defined?

Both `Boat` and `Car` initialize `Vehicle` with a call to `super().__init__()`.

Do I need to initialize `Boat` and `Car` one by one in the init of `AmphibiousVehicle`?

Or can I just call `super` once? If I do that, I don't see how `Car` gets initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses *cooperative multiple inheritance*. That means that your call to `super()` doesn't necessarily hit the base class of where it's called, it hits the next class in the *method resolution order* (MRO) from where you started.

To demonstrate:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A.__init__")
        super().__init__()

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("B.__init__")
        super().__init__()

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C.__init__")
        super().__init__()

c = C()
```

Gives the output:

```
C.__init__
A.__init__
B.__init__
```

So the call `super().__init__()` inside class `A` calls `__init__()` in class `B`, even though class `A` does not inherit from class `B`.

So long as all your classes make sure they call `super` where appropriate, you only need to call it once and trust that everything will cooperate.

The MRO is basically the order in which python will search the classes for a method or attribute. You can examine what this order is by inspecting the `__mro__` attribute on a class:

```py
print(C.__mro__)
```

Gives us:

```
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Comment: But what if both `A, B` themselves inherit from `AA, BB` (and in my case `AA = BB`)? Then when will their inits get called?

Comment: If both A and B inherit from AA, the MRO would be C->A->B->AA (and then ->object, implicitly). You can query what the MRO is by examining the `__mro__` attribute on a class.

Comment: @sakuew2 if both `Car` and `Boat` call `super().__init__` in their init, init of `Vehicle` will be called. Because, when they call `super.init`, `AmphibiousVehicle` calls `Car.init` which calls `Boat.init` which then calls `Vehicle.init`

Comment: Yes, exactly, so long as they all call `super.__init__()`

Comment: Okay, but here's what I don't understand. You say `Boat.init` calls `Vehicle.init`. But that means `Car.init` does NOT call `Vehicle.init`. That means that there may be a method IN `Car` that calls a method in `Vehicle`. So what happens? Is that method automatically deferred to `Boat' and THEN to Vehicle?

Comment: Ah, so it seems like `Boat` takes precedene in that case. ok ok i got it